# What is this wrench icon in Prey (2017)?

Tags: prey

During the 2nd mission after I come out of my apartment. I'm doing some exploring and see this icon:

[image]

I haven't been able to figure out what it does. I've tried smashing, right clicking, etc. Nothing.

Can anyone tell me what this is for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the answer. The icon shows through the wall. It's actually an indicator to repair items.

Like so:

[image]