# Repairable computer?

Tags: prey

Very early in Prey, before you even get to the foyer of the Neuromod Division, there's a computer with a repair symbol on it:

[image: Image of repairable computer]

When facing the computer, it's over the "Files" button. I've circled the computer though, and can't find any prompt to actually repair it. I've beat the game twice, and this is the only repairable computer I've seen.

Is this a bug, or is there actually a way to repair the computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found two threads ([Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/480490/discussions/0/1327844097123011127/) and [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/prey/comments/69n37s/wrench_symbol_on_computer_screen/)) about this issue (possibly even the same computer - though I can't tell), and both of them mention two things:

1. It is a bug
2. There may be [something behind it that's repairable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/308439/what-is-this-wrench-icon-in-prey-2017)

They believe it's a bug since the computers appear to be working otherwise.  The Steam source also suggests you might need the hacking option neuromod.

Comment: Sorry. My Google-Fu must be weak this morning. And I just want to note that in this particular case, if you circle around the computer, the symbol is always directly on it, so it's not something behind it. I also didn't see any repair options when I had maxed out hacking. Thanks for the references!

Comment: It's most likely a bug. I remember needing to repair that computer on my first playthrough, though the symbol never went away. On my second (no mods) playthrough, the computer was never broken in the first place.